# Tableless Table Layout in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, header, footer

Is there as way to replicate **exactly** this layout without table (using CSS and divs only, no Javascript) in **IE8**:

http://jsfiddle.net/u0u7snh6/2/

I've tried multiple scenarios and **IE8** seems to be either messing:

- Height of the content cell

  - Either there height doesn't use 100% of the space available
  - Either the height uses more than 100% and cause overflow that cannot be removed
- Alignment of the content cell

The word **exactly** is very important here... anything other than this layout will not work and **IE8** is mandatory.

Otherwise, is using tables for layout a big deal in 2014?

Here is the simple code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<table id="contentFrame">
    <tr style="background-color: pink;">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="contentCol">
            This is the header
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="contentRow">
        <td></td>
        <td id="contentCell">
            This is the content
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
        <td></td>
        <td>
            This is the footer
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#contentFrame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    empty-cells: show;
}

#contentRow {
    background-color: green;
}

#contentCell {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: white;
}

#contentCol {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: I thought windows dropped support for IE8?

Comment: Have you made an attempt and have specific issues with it?

Comment: And how is this significantly different from your question just 2 hours earlier? [Header/Footer Layout with 100% Content Height in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583701/header-footer-layout-with-100-content-height-in-ie8)

Comment: IE8 is only there on Windows XP. A lot of companies are stuck with Windows XP and thus, IE8... that's why I need to support it for a specific project.

Comment: Tables should be used to present tabular data and not full website layouts - [LINK](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/why-arent-we-supposed-to-use-table-in-a-design/6037)

Comment: I have made several attemps - I tried to ask this other question and didn't manage to get any answers (based on my attempt): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583701/header-footer-layout-with-100-content-height-in-ie8. So I thought I would try to ask an open question instead.

Comment: I agree that using table for a layout is not ideal but I was unable to find a better solution, hence why I am here :)

Comment: In 2014 instead of table's layout use HTML5 (NEW) tags - `<header>` `<nav>` `<footer>` `<article>` `<aside>` and [more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list) :)

Comment: I already use HTML5 in my other example (and HTMLShiv for IE8). The problem is really that the <div> doesn't not play nice in IE8, even if I pick 'display: table'. I've tried several options and got the problems mentioned in the top of my question :(

Comment: IE8 has been deprecated for at least 2 years now, unless you're working on an ATM interface...

Comment: I'm fine with the concept of deprecation and all. Unfortunately for this specific project I need to support both IE8 users and Blackberries which makes it a bit tricky if you also want to implement a responsive design. Having this simple layout would solve a lot of problem... considering the responses I think I'll stick to the tables since it works perfectly :)

Comment: It's hard to explain... maybe check my original question from earlier today for details on the IE8 misbehaviors with "table divs": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583701/header-footer-layout-with-100-content-height-in-ie8

Comment: TRY - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7b686k17/1/) and use min-width and max-width instead of `width % values` and use CSS [@media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Learn More: Mozilla MDN [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) & [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) and Good Luck! :)

Comment: Ok thanks for the demo but what I'm trying to do is actually have the following elements: header row (full row + content which is centered with the content), content row (again centered with the header), footer similar to the header... both the header and footer must be able to adjust their height dynamically while the content's height will always take the rest of the space. That's why a 9x9 table seems the easiest solution for this problem (HTML5 wasn't able to help)

Comment: tell me the min-width, max-width, height, background-color and position of each elements???